# Xcode 9 build fails for armv7 architecture/ simd build errors

Tags: xcode, ios11, xcode9

We were recently trying to upgrade our app from Xcode 8 to 9 and faced some issues with the same.

1. Current deployment target of the app is 9.0
2. The only change we had to do to our project to support compiling on Xcode was upgrading our SQLite library from 3.17.0 to 3.19.3
3. The build and installation work fine for the simulators as well as devices (from iOS 9 to iOS 11).
4. But the “Generic iOS Device” build (and consequently the archiving) fails.
5. Please refer to the pic below for the error thrown.
6. When we only mark “arm64” as a valid architecture, the build succeeds.
7. The build also succeeds when the deployment target is moved from 9.0 to 11.0, though the compilation process confirms that the armv7 architecture is skipped in this case.

[Errors thrown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M64Vn.png)

The error stack thrown has the following errors

```
error: definition of builtin function '__wfi' static __inline__ void
__attribute__((__always_inline__, __nodebug__)) __wfi(void) { error: definition of builtin function '__wfe' static __inline__ void
__attribute__((__always_inline__, __nodebug__)) __wfe(void) { error: definition of builtin function '__sev' static __inline__ void
__attribute__((__always_inline__, __nodebug__)) __sev(void) { error: definition of builtin function '__sevl' static __inline__ void
__attribute__((__always_inline__, __nodebug__)) __sevl(void) { error: definition of builtin function '__yield' static __inline__ void
__attribute__((__always_inline__, __nodebug__)) __yield(void) { fatal error: could not build module '_Builtin_intrinsics'
#include   fatal error: could not build module 'simd'
#import   fatal error: could not build module 'AVFoundation'
#import   fatal error: could not build module 'Photos'
#import "Photos/Photos.h"
```

Comment: Did you get this fixed?

Answer (score 2):

32-bit (armv7) is no longer supported in iOS 11, so you should make sure the deployment target be < iOS 11.
This would build both armv7 and arm64, and can run on iOS 11 and earlier.